# Comparing the same number between two different size matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am doing my simulation but I cant really get the answer that I want.
The following is my code:

```
req = [8 2 7; 2 4 5; 3 5 7];
time = [2 1 7; 3 4 6; 4 6 1];
max_time = max(max(time));
for i = 1 : 3
    timeline(:, i) = 1 : 1 : max_time;
    new(:, i) = setxor(timeline(:, i), time(:, i));
end
disp(timeline);
disp(new);
for i = 1 : 3
    for k = i : 4
        timeline(timeline(:, i) == new(k, i)) = 0;
    end
end
disp(timeline);
```

suppose the answer that I should get is timeline equal [0 1 1;2 0 0;3 0 0;4 4 0;0 0 0;0 0 0;0 6 6;0 0 7]. The number that are in timeline which do not equal to new then it will replace to 0. Thank you for helping.

how about if the time is 3 dimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

Not my language so I can't say, but until someone else posts a better answer I'll give you some direction.  Try making some simplified functions that don't do anything but take parameters and pass them to any functions they call.  Your problem seems to be with the signature of your functions and how you're trying to call them, and once you eliminate everything else but that then the answer will probably jump out at you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, it can be solved using [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html). Consider the following:

```
time = [2 1 7; 3 4 6; 4 6 1];                 %# row indices
c = repmat(1:size(time,2),size(time,1),1);    %# column indices

timeline = zeros(max(time(:)),size(time,2));  %# prepare result matrix
idx = sub2ind(size(timeline), time(:),c(:));  %# convert to linear indices
timeline(idx) = time;                         %# place the number in the matrix
```

The result:

```
>> time
time =
     2     1     7
     3     4     6
     4     6     1

>> timeline
timeline =
     0     1     1
     2     0     0
     3     0     0
     4     4     0
     0     0     0
     0     6     6
     0     0     7
```

---

### EDIT

If `time` contains zero elements, you have to skip those values. Example:

```
time = [2 1 7; 3 0 6; 0 0 1];
c = repmat(1:size(time,2),size(time,1),1);

ind = ( time(:)~=0 );                             %# non-zero entries

timeline = zeros(max(time(:)),size(time,2));
idx = sub2ind(size(timeline), time(ind),c(ind));  %# skip zero indices
timeline(idx) = time(ind);                        %# skip zero indices
```

Comment: thank you, this is helpful but the problem is when the time is time = [2 1 7;3 0 6;0 0 1]then an error is occurred saying that "Out of range subscript"

Comment: thanks for your help. when i doing 3D array, this solution cannot apply in it. for example, time is 3D array, if I using this solution then it will have another error in the idx part.how do i solve it? i have try it but still cannot solve it. i appreciate your help. thank you.